# theme studio for jscookmenu

Tags: java, javascript, menu

I'm trying to run [theme studio for jscookmenu](http://tapestry-jsmenu.sourceforge.net/theme-builder/), by double-clicking the file `js-cook-menu_2.30.jar`. But when I do that, I get the following message:

*"Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from C:\dev\tapestry-jsmenu_2.30\js-cook-menu_2.30.jar"*

After searching on the internet, I found that it is necessary to specify a `main` class in the file `manifest.mf` of a jar file in order to run it. I thought that if I modified `js-cook-menu_2.30.jar` and I add a `manifest.mf` specifying a class with a `main` method, I could run the program.

I looked on the source code provided with the downloadable package, but no success.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is exactly what it says it is. A `main` *class* and a `main` *method* of another class are very different things. Per your error message, the documentation and what you found from looking you need to add a `main` class, so that's what I would recommend doing.